# Fetching attribute from JSON string with JSON_VAL cause "<attribute> is invalid in the used context" error

Tags: sql, json, db2, ibm-connections, hcl-connections

A proprietary third-party application stores JSON strings in it's database like this one:

```
{"state":"complete","timestamp":1614776473000}
```

I need the timestamp and found out that
[DB2 offers JSON functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/json/src/tpc/db2z_jsonfunctions.html). Since it's stored as string in the `PROF_VALUE` column, I guess that converting with `SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON` is required, before I can use `JSON_VAL` to fetch the timestamp:

```
SELECT SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL(SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(PROF_VALUE), "timestamp", "f")
FROM EMPINST.PROFILE_EXTENSIONS ext
WHERE PROF_PROPERTY_ID = 'touchpointState'
```

This causes an error that *timestamp* is invalid in the used context ( SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14). The same error is thown when I remove the `JSON2BSON` call like this

```
SELECT SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL(PROF_VALUE, "timestamp", "f")
```

Also not working with the same error (different data-types):

```
SELECT SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL(SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(PROF_VALUE), "state", "s:1000")
SELECT SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL(PROF_VALUE) "state", "s:1000")
```

I don't understand this error. My syntax is like the documented  `JSON_VAL ( json-value , search-string , result-type)` and it is the same like in the examples, where they show how to fetch the `name` field of an object.

I also played around a bit with `JSON_TABLE` to use raw input data for testing (instead of the database data), but it seems not suiteable for that.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SYSTOOLS.JSON_TABLE( SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON('{"state":"complete","timestamp":1614776473000}'), 'state','s:32')) DATA
```

This gave me a table with one row: Type = 2 and Value = complete.

Comment: you have to use single quotes `'timestamp'` is a string `"timestamp"` is a reference to an object called timestamp with case sensitivity, and `"s:1000"` is another reference

Comment: Db2 LUW has two JSON implementations, one is BSON-based, one is text-based. You don't need the 2BSON function

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems in my query: First it seems that double quotes `"` are for *object references*. I wasn't aware that there is any difference, because in most databases I used yet, both single `'` and double quotes `"` are equal.

The second problem is, that `JSON_VAL` needs to be called without `SYSTOOLS`, but the reference is still needed on `SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(PROF_VALUE)`.

With those changes, the following query worked:

```
SELECT JSON_VAL(SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(PROF_VALUE), 'timestamp', 'f')
FROM EMPINST.PROFILE_EXTENSIONS ext
WHERE PROF_PROPERTY_ID = 'touchpointState'
```